# add class to the children if parent has a "translate" class and remove "translate" class of the parent after

Tags: javascript, jquery

have any idea for this?

example code:

```
<td>
  <div class="translate">
    <p><span>Hello world</span></p>
    <p><strong>hellow <span>there</span></strong</p>
  </div>
</td>
```

the output should  be

```
<td>
  <div class="">
    <pclass="translate"><span class="translate">Hello world</span></p>
    <p class="translate"><strong class="translate">hellow <span class="translate">there</span></strong</p>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".translate").removeClass("translate").children().addClass("translate");
```

Comment: will this loop only once? I'm afraid it might also remove the class already already on the element,

Comment: The .children() function only works on direct children, see here for details: [http://api.jquery.com/children/](http://api.jquery.com/children/).  You could always add another .childen().addClass("translate"), but that depends on if you know how many times you will need to loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p.translate").removeClass("translate").children().addClass("whatever");
```